# Split audio into tracks?

Tags: audio, music

I've recorded some music from an internet radio stream. I want to split it into separate audio tracks, preferably automatically (where ever there's a pause, or using some other clever algo). Anyone know of some software that can do this?

The mp3 file is about 500 megs. There actually aren't many silences as it's sort of club remix and the songs fade into each other. The only stops are when the radio announcer says a few words... I'd like to cut those bits out and split the tracks there if possible.

Answer (score 1):

The '[Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/)' package can do this to a a point.Open your audio file in Audacity, and then go to Analyze and then Silence Finder. This will plot your track breaks on a new track called the Label Track. You will have to fine tune this track manually (some songs do have silence in them legitimately). Naming the tracks in the label track will also allow you to export the pieces. To do THAT, go to File -> Export Multiple. Pick your output format and how you want the files named, and you should be ready to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mp3splt](http://mp3splt.sourceforge.net/mp3splt_page/home.php) to do this, if you know when the lengths of the labels.